# What is h2 with disk-based persistence in jhipster

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

I am new to jhipster, while starting I was asked to choose between

H2 with disk-based persistence

H2 with in-memory persistence

MySQL

databases what are the differences between these.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We currently use **H2 in-memory** persistence by default. It's easy to
> use, but of course you lose your data at each restart (and need to log
> in again as you lose your persistent session token), which is
> annoying.
>
> We could use **H2 disk-based** persistence by default, and save the
> database state in the target/ directory:

Comment: Can i deploy h2 disk-based application to server like heroku

Comment: Sorry,. hmm i have to search for it.. wait @watchit

Answer (score 3):

You will need to choose the database depending on your need.
The default of JHipster are:

- For **development** h2-diskbase which is a `free SQL database written in Java`. When you start/run your app, the database will be a file saved under `target` directory your project root.
- For **production** it's MySQL. If choosen mysql JHipster offers a docker ready configuration file which you can used to start the database under `src/main/docker/mysql.yml`.

And as for the comment on deploying to Heroku you have H2 disk & memory base, and [Postgres Addon Heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) for free. There is an nice example of an JHipster application deployed to heroku with Postgres from Matt Raible at his free book [The JHipster Mini-Book 2.0](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/jhipster-2-mini-book).

**EDIT:** Most relationnal databases are supported by JHipster both in production and development (MySQL, PostGreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server ...). Just modify your *application-dev.yml* or *application-prod.yml* accordingly. **I don't recommend** using h2 in production, even the **disk-based version**. If we take your Heroku deployment need into account, PostGreSQL is a great choice with a large community and enough features for a normal app.